# Having trouble with jmHighlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highlight

I am very new to Javascript (ok, I've done 'Hello World' alright =]) and my other web programming skills are very limited.

I am trying to implement jmHighlight into one of my already created webpages but found I can't even get it to work in a clean page of its own.  I've obviously made a very rudimentary mistake somewhere but can't figure out where so I'm hoping someone can help.

Here's what I've tried which doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .context {
                font-size:14px;
                font-family:verdana;
            }
            span.highlight {
            background-color:#000000;
            font-color:#ffffff;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.jmHighlight.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="context">some text</p>
        <input type="button" value="Try it" onclick="myFunc()">
        <script>
            function myFunc(){
                jQuery(".context").jmHighlight("some");
                alert("Done!");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `alert` works so I think the basic code is ok, I think its more the syntax of the plugin I've gotten wrong.  The author shows his work here:  [here on GitHub](https://github.com/julmot/jmHighlight) and altered his syntax in section 2 for a fixed keyword ('some') instead of using a text box for now.  The include is in the same location as my page, but doesn't show in the debugger when I preview the page as loaded...

I have also tried lifting the code from his [basic example Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/vpav6tL1/) but still can't get it to work.  I've also had a look at other jmHighlight questions here on SO, but can't manipulate them to work for me.

If someone could kindly point me in the right direction, or supply me with a very simple but complete working example that I can dissect myself to figure out where I went wrong, I'd be very appreciative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working in Chrome, I have tried it and here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/sf5cbkp6/1/) which also shows it is working.
The only thing I think may not be right is your path to jmHighlight or the version of jmHighlight.

jmHighlight was also renamed to jquery.mark. Here is a rawgit URL pointing to the .min.js:
`https://rawgit.com/julmot/jquery.mark/master/dist/jquery.mark.min.js`

Comment: Gah! Thankyou!  Hours of messing around and it was just the source reference...  To be honest, I followed the instructions on the repo which just said to download the .js and include it locally. I'd obviously done something wrong there I think.  I should also note that `font-color` didn't seem to work for me, but `color` did.

Comment: Can I ask, on the fiddle, why have you tied the button into a Javascript function with the button's `id` rather than with the `onclick` in the `<input>` tag?

Comment: I was also wondering this, but I suspect that's because on jsfiddle html is rendered before javascript, which makes the function specified in onclick unavailable. :)

Comment: You're welcome, and color works because it's the attribute to set the color, font-color is not a recognized css styling attribute.

Comment: I'm now trying to implement this in another page in which the target is an iframe.  I can get the instance to work with the button and the target ('context') in the same and seperate elements of the page (div tags and tables), but I cannot get it to work if the "context" is in the iframe, which is showing an external page.  If I give the iframe the "context" class (and remove the class from the test div), the code will not run at all (not even an alert).  Is what I am trying to do here possible and am I going the right way about it?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case of those following, if I place a `<div>` around the `<iframe>` with `class="context"` the code will also not run at all, but if I take the `<iframe>` out, the code will run again so I'm wondering if there is an issue with jmHighlight and iframes - maybe encountering an element that is not compatible just causes the code to end?  I don't know enough to know for sure and as my original question has been answered, I'll continue my findings elsewhere and post here where that is if I find a solution.  Thanks again to Ammar.

Comment: it's actually a tough ask because being able to modify contents of iframe is a security risk, and I'm afraid that you may not be able to highlight text in iframe from parent document. However if the iframe is display a site, whose code you can modify, then you can send message from parent to iframe, and then iframe (if it supports jwHighlight) can highlight the text.

Comment: This is what I wondered - whether using jmHighlight is considered 'modifying' as the external webpage is a different domain which I have no admin access to.  Perhaps I'm approaching what I want to do in the wrong way, which is to simply automate the 'find' function of a browser to a preset list of keywords once a page has loaded in the iframe.

Comment: @iStruggle jmHighlight was renamed to jquery.mark and now supports also iframes. In future, please [open an issue](https://github.com/julmot/jquery.mark/issues/new) on the repository on GitHub to get immediate support.